# Chromium Ninja build fails (Illegal Instruction output)

Tags: chromium, ninja

I followed the [Linux build instructions](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxBuildInstructions) and when I try running "ninja -C out/Debug chrome", I just get the output "Illegal Instruction (core dumped)".  Now, I wish I could actually find where the core dump is located to see if there is more specific information in there...

For reference, I am trying to run Ninja on Ubuntu 13.10.

Has anyone else experienced this while building Chromium or while trying to build anything else using Ninja?  Also, where could I find the core dump?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't built Chromium in 13.10, but I've done it many times in 12.10. Try to pass '-v' flag to get more information while building. Also, unless you're interesting in debugging, building 'Release' will be much faster. Summarizing, what "ninja -v -C out/Release chrome" says?

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Illegal Instruction (core dumped)" indicates that the current binary is using an instruction that is not supported by your CPU.

Please check whether software used for compilation (compiler, linker, ar, ninja-build etc.) is matching your CPU architecture. Unless you have no fancy system like ARM or POWER, you mixed up 32 bit (e.g. i586) and 64 bit (x86-64).

Or you compile to a wrong target. Does your compiler flags include flags beginning with -m like "-march="? That could lead to the same error but only if the compiled code is executed.
Have you built gyp or ninja-build yourself? This would be an other place to make such a mistake.